# Android: removing Sherlock Action Bar items for some classes

Tags: android, contextmenu, share, actionbarsherlock

I'm having Sherlock Action Bar to show several icons in the Action Bar, like sharing, info, etc.

The thing is that I want to delete, for certain activities/fragments one of the buttons (sharing), but I can't do it.

My activity (StartActivity) extends from InfoActivity, which is the one that implements the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

I tried to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method and do a `clear()` but it doesn't work:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end, was creating different classes: one with the Sharing button in the menu as a button, and one without, and just making the proper activity extend from the appropriate class.

For example, StartActivity, I don't want it to have sharing capabilities, so I made it extend from an Activity without the sharing button.

Thanks @NikolayElenkov for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Find the menu item in question and disable or hide it. Something like this in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` if you want to make it dynamic:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share).setVisible(false);
```

Comment: When doing a `menu.findItem` I get a `NullPointerException` because there are no items.

Comment: Well, you need to inflate the menu first to get the items.

Comment: could it be that this doesn't work since I'm not populating the MenuItems in the Action Bar from an XML, but I'm adding them dynamically?

Comment: Well, if you are adding dynamically, just don't add it :) Or use `setVisible()/setEnabled()` when you create a menu item.

Comment: No but the problem, is that if in the InfoActivity I inflate it from XML, in StartActivity, when I do another inflate, I get double the icons, and if I try to hide them, I can only hide the ones that have been generated in StartActivity.. don't know if I'm explaining myself :)

Comment: Well either move logic in the base activity (use an abstract method if you need to), or don't call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()` in the subclass. You might want to show more code if that doesn't make sense.